# vue.js vuex-persistedstateの代替ライブラリについて

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

vuex-persistedstateを使って、storeの永続化をしていますが、
セキュリティの観点から使用を控えたく、代替になるライブラリ等、手段はありますでしょうか。
（なるべく同じ書きっぷりで使えるものがあれば良いのですが、、）
よろしくお願いします。